# Sitecore 8 Glass Mapper template field language versions not being created

Tags: templates, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I'm currently in the process of a new Sitecore 8 (Update 5) build and decided to use Glass Mepper (Glass.Mapper.Sc.4.0.3.51) code first templates. At runtime the templates are being created as expected under the "GlassTemplates" folder. However the fields and field sections are all missing language versions which is causing issues when publishing these to the web database?

This is an example class:

```
[SitecoreType(CodeFirst = true, TemplateId = TemplateStringId, TemplateName = TemplateDescription)]
public class Website
{

    #region "Template And Field Ids"
    public static Guid TemplateId = new Guid(TemplateStringId);
    private const string TemplateDescription = "Website Configuration";
    private const string TemplateStringId = "{2CC88217-A2BE-433F-B7D5-7CF75BF49B4E}";
    private const string FooterLinksFieldId = "{82649401-1425-43FC-B73D-B19BE953FEF4}";
    private const string SocialLinksFieldId = "{0B631B01-8996-406F-B3F3-53F3A0395AE4}";
    private const string GoogleAnalyticsCodeFieldId = "{69312587-DAD8-4FAA-8BF1-CD3C95F5C574}";
    #endregion

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = FooterLinksFieldId, FieldName = "Footer Links", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Multilist, SectionName = Sections.WebsiteConfiguration, CodeFirst = true)]
    public virtual string FooterLinks { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = SocialLinksFieldId, FieldName = "Social Links", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Multilist, SectionName = Sections.WebsiteConfiguration, CodeFirst = true)]
    public virtual string IncludeInNavigation { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = GoogleAnalyticsCodeFieldId, FieldName = "Google Analytics Code", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText, SectionName = Sections.WebsiteConfiguration, CodeFirst = true)]
    public virtual string GoogleAnalyticsCode { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something I could be missing here?